# PiTFT: broken C4 resistor

Tags: pitft

i got my new PiTFT. To assemble it i flipped the Display to solder the GPIO port.
Then i saw that the C4 resistor was stuck on the top part and broke.

Can i use the PiTFT without the C4 (What is the function of C4). Has someone an idea to reassemble it, because if i use the soldering iron it will melt the platic.

[image]

Comment: Although the soldering iron may leave visible marks on the plastic, it won't do any serious damage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, C4 is a capacitor, not a resistor.

Secondly, the iron won't melt the plastic, how do you think the capacitor got there in the first place? Having said that, I would recommend to use thin tip low-power iron for electronics (15-20W), not the 100W+ industrial type.

Beware, you'll need 3 hands to successfully solder the part, one hand to hold the capacitor in place, another one to use the iron and the third one to feed the iron with the thin (0.3mm~0.5mm recommended) solder. It might be a good idea to use a solder wick on the capacitor pads to remove leftover solder before soldering it back (or not, if you feel adventurous =)

Comment: How hard would it be to place the whole board in with C4 in place in an oven to solder it?

Comment: would not recommend that. after all, it's much easier to fix with the iron. you may practice on broken SMD-mounted PCB, if you like, to get the confidence.